# What is a predictable commit sha to use when merging pull request to a master using GitHub actions?

Tags: git, github-actions

I am using [github-actions]. I have two worksflows:

- triggered on `pull_request`
- triggered on `push`

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
```

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
```

The `pull_request` workflow generates assets that need be used in `push` workflow. I need some sort of an identifier that would allow me to connect the two workflows, ideally SHA of git merge commit. However, I was not able to identify a reliable reference to use.

At the moment I am using `${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}` in `pull_request` workflow, and in `push` workflow I am using:

```yaml
- name: Setup repository
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
    fetch-depth: 2
- name: Set CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA env property
  shell: bash
  run: echo "CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA=$(git rev-parse --short=8 HEAD^2)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

This works most of the time but breaks when commits are force pushed to the PR branch before it is merged.

What is a reliable [git](/questions/tagged/git) reference to associate `pull_request` with `push` workflows?

Comment: Just curious, why you don't just use the `GITHUB_SHA` env variable?

Comment: It has different value in `pull_request` and `push` workflows.

Comment: Related question [How to get last commit sha from pull_request in push action?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69749929/368691)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking to trigger the second workflow only on a PR merge to master, you could use the `pull_request.closed` event. From within that workflow, `$GITHUB_REF` should get you the reference to the PR merge branch (refs/pull/:prNumber/merge). Would that work for you to tie the two workflows together?

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
    types: [closed]
```

Also, note that to ignore closed PRs that weren't merged, you'll need to add a condition in your job to skip it in that case: `if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true`