# How to get last commit sha from pull_request in push action?

Tags: github, github-actions

In the context of [github-actions](/questions/tagged/github-actions), how do I get sha of the last commit in the PR before it was merged?

I want to get this sha in the context of `push` workflow, i.e.

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
```

If push was not triggered by a PR merge, then I need a way to ignore the action.

Comment: This will likely also answer my another question: [What is a predictable commit sha to use when merging pull request to a master using GitHub actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69749136/368691), though they are different questions.

Comment: I guess using `https://github.com/marketplace/actions/find-current-pull-request` will help, check if the PR number is an empty string then stop the action.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using {{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }} and comparing it to ${{ github.sha }}

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it on push, but if you do it on a pull request merge, you can do something like this

```
name: implementation

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [closed]

jobs:
  job1:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true # So it only runs on merged
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - env:
          EVENT_NAME: ${{ github.event_name }}
          PULL_HEAD_SHA: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}
        run: |
          echo event type: $EVENT_NAME
          echo pull head sha: $PULL_HEAD_SHA
          git fetch
          echo sha last: $(git rev-parse $PULL_HEAD_SHA)
          echo sha last: $(git rev-parse --short $PULL_HEAD_SHA)
```